# Calculate total price by checking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a script that gets a number based on checked checkboxes, then there is a input where users can input a number which then gets calculated with my total numbers that I got from checkboxes. So my issue is that the total number doesn't gets updated when I uncheck/check checkbox again, and I need it to automatically update.

```js
// Total Price Calculator
function calc() {
  var tots = 0;
  $(".checks:checked").each(function() {
    var price = $(this).attr("data-price");
    tots += parseFloat(price);
  });

  $("#no-text").keyup(function() {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    $('#tots').text(value*tots.toFixed(2));
  });

}
$(function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".checks", calc);
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">

<input type="number" id="no-text" placeholder="10">

<span id="tots">0.00</span>
```

So I need all of this to be done automatically, if I check 1st and 2nd checkbox and set input to number 5 it will calculate the price, then if I uncheck one checkbox it should update the price automatically according to already inputted number without need to update it again.

Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind you've started down the path of a well known coding issue; duplicate event binding.  Your keyup binding is inside another event binding, which means every time that the outer event happens, it's going to create a duplicate event binding for the keyup.  You should only be binding once, to avoid logical conflicts

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to jQuery and javascript so any of this suggestions means a lot. Can you give me a hand with it? I have added it outside, the keyup binding, but it won't work then. I guess its because I can't fetch the variables anymore when im outside and I need to call them again inside my keyup bind function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple elements in one event handler, so include `#no-text` so that they'll both fire the calc event when either the checkbox or the input is updated

Then move `$('#tots').text((number * tots).toFixed(2))` out of the old event listener, and add another variable to fetch the value of the input element

```js
// Total Price Calculator
function calc() {
  // Get value from input
  let number = parseFloat($('#no-text').val() || 0);
  let tots = 0;
  
  // Add Checkbox values
  $(".checks:checked").each(function() {
    tots += $(this).data("price");
  });
  
  // Update with new Number
  $('#tots').text((number * tots).toFixed(2));
}

$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '.checks, #no-text', calc);
  calc();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">
<input type="checkbox" class="checks" data-price="10">

<input type="number" class="duration-input" id="no-text" placeholder="10">

<span id="tots">0.00</span>
```

Comment: Also note the added parentheses around `number * tots`.

Comment: `$(this).data('price')` would reduce the logic a bit.  `data()` auto converts values to numbers/booleans/arrays/objects, whatever it can intelligently guess the value is

Comment: This works man, thanks so much. Any suggestions on how can I remove NaN when no number is inputted?

Comment: `parseFloat($('#no-text').val() || '0');`